# Best way to deal with csv , for preparation for mySql

Tags: mysql, database, csv, format

We have a CSV file, which we have meticulously checked and stripped to show the data in the format we want.

As such this csv file is, just under 500kb in size. I have converted to sql ( saved as txt ) hope thats ok.

The original csv data entry is 3 fields, as thus:

'STANLEY','7331','TAS'

'GORMANSTON','7466','TAS'

After conversion its like so:

INSERT INTO suburbs (`'Locality'`,`'Pcode'`,`'State'`) VALUES ('\'STANLEY\'','\'7331\'','\'TAS\'');

INSERT INTO suburbs (`'Locality'`,`'Pcode'`,`'State'`) VALUES ('\'GORMANSTON\'','\'7466\'','\'TAS\'');

Ok now, not being a db officianado, I would like to know. Have I converted it correctly ?
Should I be looking at making this code cleaner for import to the db.

The sql is over 1.6 mb for this file, with over 16,000 entries, so want to make sure I have done things correctly.

Cheers

Comment: You probably don't want to be inserting the single-quotes in the database around the values.

Comment: So... no one told you about [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html), so you could load data via CSV?

Comment: +1 OMG Ponies took the words right out of my mouth and to boot, not a single answer suggesting it - egads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with what Adam's comment said, you're most likely not going to want to insert the quotes, which you are doing with \'STANLEY\'  etc.

Also, on the 'field' side (locality etc), make sure those are back ticks (non-shift tilde), and the data side (STANLEY) are single quotes.

change to:

```
INSERT INTO suburbs (`Locality`,`Pcode`,'State`) VALUES ('STANLEY','7331','TAS');
```

Other than that, I don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: so: do I need INSERT INTO suburbs on every single line: or as I was thinking, 
Insert INTO suburbs
Values (Locality,Pcode,State)
Values (blah,blahblah,deeblah);

Comment: Well you can have each row on their own line, like my example shows... or you can use the LOAD DATA INFILE command if your csv matches the table exactly,  OR you _CAN_ do multiple inserts like "INSERT INTO suburbs (`a`,`b`,`c`) VALUES('1','2','3'),('4','5','6'),('7','8','9)"  However, with as much data as you have, you wont be able to do it in 1 INSERT line, you will still have to construct a few lines, but you can do maybe up to 100 inserts per insert into line... I think it has something to do with line length... You're better off just doing 1 row per line

Comment: Thanks, yeah i was gonna do one per line, my concern was buffer, as I am sure I read most we can transfer is 130kb at a time. So wasnt sure on best way to import, normally I just nip onto phpmyadmin, create a db, and then import .. the worry being how big a bugger can we physically import, and do I just chop the file up into say 1000 rows at a time, and do 16 imports... if that makes sense

Answer (score 2):

Looks fine, other than the escaped quotes. I use this technique usually with an excel file. Where I have my columns and then I create a formula to generate the appropriate insert statements. Alternatively you can use something like SSIS to get your data into your db.

Comment: Thanks, I was just gonna plonk the lot in the mysql via phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL looks good, although won't the extra escaped single quotes end up in your records? I'm not sure if you want 'STANLEY' or just STANLEY in your records, so I'll leave it up to you.

You have half of your work done. You have an insert strategy, do you have a rollback strategy as well? It seems as if this is a big data migration for you, if I might so humbly suggest that you try the insert with just a few rows in a junk table that you don't mind getting rid of first. It's always a pain if the changes have to be undone and there is nothing in place or ready to go to undo any errors.

Comment: Yeah , dunno where they came from, guess was the migration conversion from our csv, expecting that the ' was indeed part of the data which it isnt.